# VB.NET: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs'.'

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a program that has a textbox and I need to monitor the user input to allow only characters, whitespaces and control operations. This is all the code I have:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.ReadOnly = False
        If TimesPressed = 0 Then
            Label2.Visible = False
            TextBox1.Text = “Welcome to VB.Net, ” & TextBox1.Text
            Button1.Text = "Repeat" 
            TextBox1.ReadOnly = True 
            TextBox1.BackColor = SystemColors.Window 
            TimesPressed = 1
        ElseIf TimesPressed = 1 Then
            Label2.Visible = True
            TextBox1.Clear() 
            Button1.Text = "Run" 
            TimesPressed = 0
        Else
            TimesPressed = 0
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) = False And Char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar) = False And Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) = False Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Then I have a button that submits the input but when I try to click on it I am presented with an error box that says:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs'.

I don't know what to do and I can't find answers that I understand anywhere. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the code for your `button` please? Including the line that's throwing the error here would be helpful in diagnosing this.

Comment: Make sure you have `Option Strict On`, either in code or in project options.  Without it, there are some allowances for signature mismatches that blow up at run time (and it really does need to be done with `Option Strict`, in my experience you can't disable the relaxed type checking through any of the individual options).

Comment: @Spevacus I've done what you asked

Comment: @MoscaCareca Your argument for `e` in your `Button1_Clicked` sub is of the type `KeyPressEventArgs` when it should be of the type `MouseEventArgs`. Try changing that type.

Comment: Your button Click event handler is wrong.... The button Click event handler doesn't handle KeyEvents... it handles mouse events... Instead of just making things up.... delete the `handles Button1.Click` from that line, go back to your form, double click the button, and look at the code the IDE generates for you... see how it then has a MouseEventArg? That's what the problem is.

Comment: @TechGnome @Spevacus  The auto-generated event handler creates an `EventArgs` type argument. This is because the `Click` event can be generated by both the keyboard and the Mouse (and by code, different topic, though). When generated by a the KeyBoard, `EventArgs` will be `EventArgs.Empty`, when [generated by a Mouse click](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,9225), it will be set to `MouseEventArgs` (and can be cast). The OP probably modified that code manually.

Comment: My previous comment was posted before the button click event handler was posted.  I'm 99% certain this code would not compile with `Option Strict On`.  It's a good idea in general, and it's absolutely essential any time you work with events (otherwise it's too easy to get a signature that's close enough to compile but different enough to cause difficult-to-diagnose problems at runtime).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure why Spevacus deleted his answer; it was correct. A button click handler is descended from the [Control.Click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.click?view=netframework-4.8) event, that takes an object of type `EventArgs` as its second parameter. When you click a button an object of type `MouseEventArgs` is created, and **this descends** from `EventArgs` as a child in the inheritance hierarchy, so it can be passed to the click handler (because a child type can always automatically be cast to any one of its parent types)

`KeyPressEventArgs` is also descended from `EventArgs` but it is a sibling of `MouseEventArgs`, not an inherited relation. As such when you click the button and a `MouseEventArgs` is created it cannot be passed to a Sub/Function that is declared to take a `KeyPressEventArgs` because there is no automatic conversion between the two. **`Mouse` and `KeyPress` share the same parent but are different things and cannot be converted.**

Long story short, change your button click handler so it takes an `EventArgs` instead of a `KeyPressEventArgs`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
```

---

As an aside, please always rename your controls after you add them to the form. There are few things worse for someone else who is reading your code and trying to help, than having to work out and remember which of 30 button X or textbox Y does what / is what - renaming them to "_inputTextBox" or "_saveButton" takes about 2 seconds and helps you out immeasurably too, as your program grows in complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments you have for `Button1_Clicked` are slightly incorrect.

Your `e` argument should be an `EventArgs` variable.

For easy copy paste, here's how its declaration should look now:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
```

As @TechGnome suggests, you should try double clicking the button in your form designer to see what the auto-generated code looks like and edit it from there. It does most of the heavy lifting for you!

Comment: That's good advice.  Do this yourself as well to see it isn't actually MouseEventArgs.  Which does leave you with the task of explaining the error message, good luck ;)